# Grid Program w/ java

Tags: java, class, awt

I am currently working on a tester program that utilized the awt class from Java. In this program, I am trying to produce 4 random dots in a specific quadrant of a grid.

*When reviewing my code, can you suggest a better route as far as organization goes?*

I am currently just using a for loop to display 4 points, like so:

```
 for (int dotsOnGrid = 1; dotsOnGrid < 5; dotsOnGrid++)
    {
        int x = (int) (Math.random() * (.50 * width)); 
        int y = (int) (Math.random() * (.50 * height));

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillOval(x, y, r, r); 
    }
```

As far as getting 4 red dots on the upper-left of the grid, I am solid.

I am just having trouble figuring out how to produce the Yellow and Green dots. How would that work while using Math.random()?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: You might want to get the coordinates randomly for all entire screen and based on what you get choose the color.

Comment: You know how to generate a random number between 0 and width / 2. You want a random number between width / 2 and width. Don't you think simply adding width / 2 would do it?

Answer (score 1):

Do some simple math and its not hard to figure out. First find out the coordinate x range for the square, and coordinate y range for the square. Do two randoms within those two ranges and that will be your x, y values. Easy.

Answer (score 0):

Just add new sections for the other colors:

```
for (int numDots = 1; numDots < 5; numDots++)
{
    g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);

    int x = (int) (Math.random() * (.50 * width)) + (.50 * width); 
    int y = (int) (Math.random() * (.50 * height));

    g.fillOval(x, y, r, r);
}


for (int numDots = 1; numDots < 5; numDots++)
{
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);

    int x = (int) (Math.random() * (.50 * width)); 
    int y = (int) (Math.random() * (.50 * height) + (.50 * height));

    g.fillOval(x, y, r, r);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(Although this smells like homework :))

Just assume you have to fill four grids with colors. For each grid of the four grids you can execute the same code. So make a function that makes a grid for one type of color (this means color will be an argument). Then once having the four grids made, paste them together into a big grid.

In pseudo code:

```
public Grid makeGrid(final Color color) {
  Grid g = new Grid();
  for(numberOfDotsPainted = 0; numberOfDotsPainted < NUMBER_OF_DOTS_TO_BE_PAINTED; ++numberOfDotsPainted) {
    // choose random spot for the new dot
    // Create a dot with the given color
    // Add the new dot to the grid
  }
  return g;
}
```

This function needs to be called for each color and then based on which color needs to go where you need to translate the coordinates to the right position. Easy math if you put your four grids on the four quadrants of the Cartesian coordinate system. (translations will exist of addition and substraction by the width of your grids).

This approach will avoid code duplication and is much more structured than copy pasting the same code over and over again with small changes in each part. Every time you need to change a small thing to the core functionality you will only need to change one part of your code instead of n times (n the amount of colors) a change. This is very error prone.

Comment: yeah, I see what you're getting at. It's much simpler to have one block of code rather than copying and pasting things n amount of times. Which is my goal in this program as it can become repetitive.

Comment: Have a go at it and let me know if it works out or not.

Comment: Obviously though, with this program, the way I have it set up, the dots don't always stay in bounds, meaning inside the grid. How would I go about fixing that minor problem based on the code I have previously written?

Comment: Is the middle of the dot inside the grid? If you take large dots then you should take into account in your code that the chosen point is at least a radius away from the border of the grid. If the dot is completely outside of the grid there is another bug.

Comment: Another hint for the quality of your code. Use constants for fixed values. final Integer r = 40 for instance and the .50 and 5 can also be put in constants, if it makes sense you can make some or all of them static constants.

And a performance appraisal: It is very good that you do .50 * width rather than (width / 2). Numerically it is harder and less precise to do a division than a multiplication ;-).